# How to skip initial screen of "Try or Install ubuntu server" in custom ISO of ubuntu22.04

Tags: 22.04, custom-installer

I'm customizing Ubuntu22.04 Installation CD, while Installing this I want to skip the below attached page (I want to display my customized page as the first page who ever is installing this). As this is the first time I'm attempting this I'm searching the online resources but couldn't get a clue. Can any one point me to right resource or give some clue?

Initial boot screen:

[image: Initial boot screen]

Comment: did you look for `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` ?

Comment: In this file I set the timeout as 0.

Comment: here is my contents of /etc/default/grub file GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

Comment: if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`````
````
sed -i -e 's/timeout=30/timeout=1/g' "${REMASTER}/boot/grub/grub.cfg"
````
`````

This line solved my issue. Thanks @Andra for your comment.